# Combining pandas group_by and sklearn countVectorizer

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, scikit-learn, classification

I have a dataframe of the form:

```
ID    col1  col2  col3   class
1     0.35  "A"    "x"  'class1'
1     0.35  "B"    "y"  'class1'
1     0.35  "A"    "x"  'class1'
1     0.35  "A"    "z"  'class1'
2     0.48  "B"    "u"  'class2'
2     0.48  "A"    "x"  'class2'
3     0.14  "C"    "v"  'class3'
```

where the dimensions of col2 and col3 are very high (above 7000 in total). I have to do a classification on the ID field. So in my understanding I need to group the data. If I use pandas group_by and use a dense format the memory explodes. So I was wondering what would be the best way to feed the data into a classifier? Is there anyway I can group the data based on counts of col2 and col3 while keeping the col1 as is and have the output in a sparse matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, I would do this by separating the `groupby` and the feature selection, so that the `groupby` just aggregates the strings, and the `CountVectorizer` is applied on these grouped strings. For example:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby('ID').aggregate({'col1':'first',
                                          'col2':'sum',
                                          'col3':'sum'})
>>> grouped['all'] = grouped['col2'] + grouped['col3']
>>> print(grouped)
    col3  col1  col2       all
ID                            
1   xyxz  0.35  ABAA  ABAAxyxz
2     ux  0.48    BA      BAux
3      v  0.14     C        Cv

>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> features = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char').fit_transform(grouped['all'])
>>> features.shape
(3, 8)
```

This should scale suitably to a large number of columns. If you need to count words rather than characters, the above solution just needs slight modifications.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply which was very helpful. Is there anyway I can include the numeric column(col 1) also into the features?

Comment: I searched a bit and hstack from scipy.sparse did the trick. Thanks once again for your assistance.